# error deploying dolly-v2-12b on Amazon SageMaker

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface

I'm trying to get https://huggingface.co/databricks/dolly-v2-12b setup and am having some difficulty.

I clicked on Deploy -> Amazon SageMaker and, in the resultant window, I set the Task to "Text Generation" and the Configuration to "Local Machine". I take the resultant python script that it gives me, I replace `{IAM_ROLE_WITH_SAGEMAKER_PERMISSIONS}` with AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionPolicy-20230418T130702 (the policy that got created for me when I tried to create a new domain using the Quick setup and the SageMaker Compute Role) and I then tried to run the Python script but doing so yields me a long delay (maybe a few minutes? idk - I haven't measured it) before giving me me this error:

```
------------!Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 28, in <module>
    predictor.predict({
  File "/home/scbn/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sagemaker/predictor.py", line 161, in predict
    response = self.sagemaker_session.sagemaker_runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(**request_args)
  File "/home/scbn/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 530, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/scbn/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 960, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from primary with message "{
  "code": 400,
  "type": "InternalServerException",
  "message": "\u0027gpt_neox\u0027"
}
". See https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1#logEventViewer:group=/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/huggingface-pytorch-inference-2023-04-20-17-06-52-252 in account 636601586062 for more information.
```

Here's a screenshot of the role in AWS's IAM manager:

[image]

Here's what I get if I click on "AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionPolicy-20230418T130702":

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Having the same problem. It could be due to this (with solution): https://towardsdatascience.com/unlock-the-latest-transformer-models-with-amazon-sagemaker-7fe65130d993. I have not tried it though.

Answer (score 2):

You may have to check the logs to get the actual error. Since the model is large chances are it might have failed due to insufficient memory and would need some kind of model parallel techniques. For large models you can refer to this deployment example to get started

https://github.com/vivekmadan2/large-models-roadshow/blob/main/lab1-deploy-llm/intro_to_llm_deployment.ipynb